# Initializing an s3 client in AWS SDK for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, aws-sdk

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-swift/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html) for the AWS SDk for Swift describe how to instantiate a service client:

```
let s3Client = try S3Client(region: "us-east-1")
```

However since this statement can throw errors it needs to be wrapped in a `do catch` block as shown on a separate [documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-swift/latest/developer-guide/using-configuration.html):

```
do {
    let s3 = try S3Client(region: "af-south-1")

    // .....
} catch {
    dump(error, name: "Error accessing S3 service")
    exit(1)
}
```

I've created a public `S3Manager` class that will contain the specific functions I want to use in my code for manipulating s3 buckets. Typically I would instantiate the client in the class initializer but since it must be wrapped in a `do catch` block I have taken a different approach:

```
public class S3manager : ObservableObject {
    
    public var client: S3Client?
    
    public func initializeClient() {
        do {
            client = try S3Client(region: "us-west-2")
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error creating S3 client: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    public func listBucketFiles(bucket: String) async throws -> [String] {
        
        if let clientInstance = client {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

In my views I will reference the class as a `StateObject` or `ObservedObject` as appropriate and be certain to call `initializeClient` before calling any other methods I implement in the class (in the initial view's `onAppear()` method for example)  Is this the best approach though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't confirm that the code below works exactly as expected because the SDK is not finding my credentials in ~/.aws/credentials`or as environment variables, but I changed my approach to contain all of the`s3` logic in it's own respective class:

```
import Foundation
import AWSS3
import ClientRuntime
import AWSClientRuntime

public class S3manager : ObservableObject {
    private var client: S3Client?
    public var files: [String]?
    
    init() {
        Task(priority: .high) {
            do {
                client = try S3Client(region: "us-west-2")
                files = try await listBucketFiles(bucket: "bucket_name")
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-swift/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html
    public func listBucketFiles(bucket: String) async throws -> [String] {
        
        if let clientInstance = client {
            let input = ListObjectsV2Input(
                bucket: bucket
            )
            let output = try await clientInstance.listObjectsV2(input: input)
            var names: [String] = []
            
            guard let objList = output.contents else {
                return []
            }
            
            for obj in objList {
                if let objName = obj.key {
                    names.append(objName)
                }
            }
            
            return names
            
        } else {
            print("Client has not been initialized!")
            return [String]()
        }
    }
}
```

This has the advantage that in `ContentView` I can simply reference the class member as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var s3 = S3manager()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(s3.files ?? ["Content Loading..."], id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```